# QML Move frameless ApplicationWindow holding the MouseArea

Tags: c++, qt, qml, window

Configuration (the more current version I can get from my company for now):

- **Qt 5.12**
- Red Hat 7.9 Linux server
- GCC 4.8.5

I am working on a project in which the title bar of the window can't be personnalize as I want (adding logo, updating button top right, ...). So I create an ApplicationWindow frameless (with Qt.FramelessWindowHint and Qt.Window flags) and add a rectangle on top on which I add all components I want.

But, without the original title bar of the window, I wasn't able to move the window anymore. So I add a MouseArea which fill my rectangle and calculate the new position of the window like this:

The `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: mainWindow

    property int    previousX:      0
    property int    previousY:      0
    property bool   isFullScreen:   false

    visible:        true
    visibility:     Qt.Window
    title:          ""
    minimumWidth:   1400
    minimumHeight:  900
    flags:          Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    Rectangle
    {
        id: mainWindowTitleBar
        anchors
        {
            top:        parent.top
            left:       parent.left
            right:      parent.right
        }
        width:          parent.width
        height:         30
        color:          "white"
        z:              1

        MouseArea
        {
            id: mouseAreaToChangePosition
            anchors.fill: parent

            onPressed:
            {
                previousX = mouseX
                previousY = mouseY
            }

            onMouseXChanged:
            {
                var dx = mouseX - previousX
                mainWindow.setX(mainWindow.x + dx)
            }

            onMouseYChanged:
            {
                var dy = mouseY - previousY
                mainWindow.setY(mainWindow.y + dy)
            }

            onDoubleClicked:
            {
                if (isFullScreen)
                {
                    mainWindow.visibility = Qt.WindowMinimized
                }
                else
                {
                    mainWindow.visibility = Qt.WindowFullScreen
                }

                isFullScreen = !isFullScreen
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

        QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

        engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
        if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
            return -1;

        return app.exec();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions that might occur during application execution
        qDebug().noquote() << "Error: " << ex.what();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

But, doing this, the move is not correct for me, because I can't "hide" half the window dragging it on the border of the screen. The minimum and maximum position accepted are the ones for which the application is fully display on screen.

Is it possible to call directly the event of the ApplicationWindow in any way to go further with this functionnality ? I saw on internet about exposing the QGuiApplication in the QML but I don't know after how to send event with new position.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let the window handle it by calling [QWindow::startSystemMove](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwindow.html#startSystemMove) from QML:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onPressed: mainWindow.startSystemMove()
}
```

Note: you can also simplify the fullscreen code by doing `visibility: isFullScreen ? Qt.WindowFullScreen : Qt.Window` in your Window and `onDoubleClicked: mainWindow.isFullScreen = !mainWindow.isFullScreen` in your MouseArea.

Comment: Thanks for the fullscreen. For the move, it seems the `startSystemMove` does not exist for Qt 5.12, too bad. Maybe you have another advice ?

Comment: I finally get Qt 6 on my Linux server ! Hip hip hip ! Hourra. I tried your solution and it is working perfectly. thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I've found that there are several issues with the accepted answer and the concept provied by author:

1. The `isFullScreen` property is redundant and will cause problems when the window is minimized by other means than by double clicking inside of MouseArea. For example if user first maximizes the window by double clicking and then invokes the `startSystemMove()` function by pressing inside the MouseArea, the window will minimize itself, but `isFullScreen` will stay `true` causing the next double click to do nothing instead of maximizing the window.
2. It's better to use `DragHandler` instead of `onPressed` inside the MouseArea, as this will invoke `startSystemMove()` when the user actually starts dragging the window around, instead of when he simply clicks inside the MouseArea.

Here is a simple borderless window which implements what I described above:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    // Menu bar in top portion of the window, with a visible frame around it
    menuBar: Frame {
        height: 50

        // Allow window dragging when inside menu bar
        Item {
            anchors.fill: parent
            DragHandler {
                id: handler
                onActiveChanged: if (active) root.startSystemMove()
            }
        }

        // Allow fullscreen <-> minimized switching
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onDoubleClicked: {
                root.visibility = (root.visibility != Qt.WindowFullScreen) ? Qt.WindowFullScreen : Qt.WindowMinimized
            }
        }

    }
```

Edit:
Upon doing further research, I've came to a conclusion that this approach is not sufficient for a "native feel" borderless window in Windows.

There are several things still wrong with this window:

1. After being maximized (Qt.WindowFullScreen), and then minimized by some button inside of the window (root.showMinimized()), the window won't stay in fullscreen mode after it's re-opened
2. [Aero Snap](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241) is not working
3. There are no window animations (maximize animation, minimize animation, ...)

The first point can be solved by QML code, however the only solution for points 2 and 3 is using WinAPI, which is a tricky thing to implement correctly if you're doing it from scratch.

So rather than trying to implement the window yourself and finding out later that it doesn't work as expected, it's better to use one of the borderless window libraries for Qt such as [this one](https://github.com/stdware/qwindowkit).